# Java Split String into Hashmap

Tags: java, regex, string, split, hashmap

I have a String:

```
String text = "a|3|bad1|0|b|6|bad1|1|c|5|bad2|1|d|2|bad1|0|e|1|bad2|0"
```

I would like to split this String by "|", save it into a HashMap, but skip "bad" and its value. Please notice that "bad" words could be "bad1" or "bad2". The result HashMap will looks like:

```
a:3
b:6
c:5
d:2
e:1
```

I'm a Python programmer, pretty new to Java. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Java 8? (JDK 1.8)

Comment: What is stopping you from finishing your code?

Comment: What have you already tried so far?

Comment: BEWARE OF Cos64 Answer. that code could produce an exception, you need to verify that tokens.length is even, otherwise tokens[i + 1] could point to null. –  Gatunox 15 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String text = "a|3|bad1|0|b|6|bad1|1|c|5|bad2|1|d|2|bad1|0|e|1|bad2|0";
String[] tokens = text.split("\\|");
Map<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i+=2) {
    if(!tokens[i].startsWith("bad")) {
        pairs.put(tokens[i], tokens[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

You may want to have a look at the API for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html) and [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Map.html).

Comment: your code could produce an exception, you need to verify that tokens.length is even, otherwise tokens[i + 1] could point to null.